# SFTP Inbound Sync Fails when deployed as war

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sftp

The spring boot app copies files from remote sftp server to shared location on network

it works fine with my embedded tomcat server inside intellij but fails when deployed as war to server with  the following message

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: sharedfolder
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.onInit(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:187)
    ... 72 more
```

Here is the code

Properties file

```
sftp.local.directory.xml.download=\\\\somename\\\parentfolder\\sharedfolder
```

Sync

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fromSftpChannel1", poller = @Poller(cron = "${sftp.cronExpression}"))
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageXMLSource() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
            sftpInboundFileSynchronizerXML());

    log.info("Local dir: " + new File(sftpLocalDirectoryDownloadXML));
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File(sftpLocalDirectoryDownloadXML));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(false);
    source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
    return source;
}
```

Comment: not much information here, but seems "sharedfolder" is not visible on the server

Comment: Agreed - maybe it's a file permission problem?